# How can I set a different profile pic for different messages sent by my Slack app?

Tags: c#, .net, webhooks, slack, slack-api

Please excuse my English. I have a Slack app that I am using to post messages. I am using a web API written in C# .NET 6.0 to post these messages.

I would like to change the profile pic based on which one of three types of content the bot is sending.

The bot used to use the Slack.Webhooks package. This lets me set up a SlackClient and SlackMessage. Then all I had to do was say client.PostAsync(message). It has a username property. But I couldn't change the username. When I changed the Username property of the SlackMessage object it still posted under the app name.

So I have started posting instead to https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage. I am following [the documentation here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#sending_messages_as_other_entities). First I set up a bot token for my app with the scopes chat:write and chat:write.customize, which says it allows me to "send messages as @My-SlackApp with a customized username and avatar". I also had to add the bot to my test channel.

Now when I changed the username in my model this is now working!

But I have tried changing the icon_url (I've also tried using icon_emoji which would also work). No matter what I do I only get the app's profile picture.

I am not sure if my app is a "classic slack app" (i created it today), but just in case I have also tried setting as_user=true, as_user=false and without as_user at all.

Here is the code that I am using to send the messages. What I expected to happen is that the message that got posted to slack would have the image (a google logo) as its profile pic. Instead, the message that got posted had my app's profile pic.

Any idea what I should be doing differently to be able to choose a custom avatar or emoji to display as my bot's profile pic for each message?

```
var slackMessage = new MySlackMessage()
{
    //As_User = false,
    Username = "My Custom Name",
    Text = "This text needs to have a google logo!",
    Icon_Url = "https://fulltimeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1024px-Google__G__Logo-1.png",
    //Icon_Emoji = ":heart:",
    Channel = "test"
};

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
    requestMessage.Content = JsonContent.Create<MySlackMessage>(slackMessage);
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

    var response = client.Send(requestMessage);

    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStream();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Here's the model I'm sending through by the way.

```
public class MySlackMessage
{
    // public bool As_User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Icon_Url { get; set; }
    // public string Icon_Emoji { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas how I can set my bots profile pic dynamically when I create the message?

Comment: If you built your app today then it's not a classic app so we can disregard that scenario. Can you confirm that you are using the bot token `xoxb` and not your user token, `xoxp`?

Comment: yes I am using the xoxb token

Comment: I'd recommend making a test call using this page: (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test) if it's successful it might mean that the issue is in your code somewhere.